# Django Tastypie - Resource with object details only

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

In Django with Tastypie, is there a way to configure a resource such that it only shows object details?

I want to have a url `/user` which returns the details of the authenticated user, as opposed to a list containing a single user object. I don't want to have to use `/users/<id>` to get the details of a user.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource

class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset        = User.objects.all()
        resource_name   = 'user'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
        serializer      = SERIALIZER      # Assume those are defined...
        authentication  = AUTHENTICATION  # "
        authorization   = AUTHORIZATION   # "

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Sow us your code - it looks like you are using [obj_get_list](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id9) instead of [obj_get](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id10).

Comment: @Tadeck I added the relevant portion of my code to the question. I'm not explicitly using any of those methods, but I guess I'd like to always use `obj_get`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do this by using a combination of the following resource methods

- [override_urls](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/resources.html#override-urls)
- [apply_authorization_limits](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/resources.html#apply-authorization-limits)

**Example user resource**

```
#Django
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf.urls import url

#Tasty
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'

        #Disallow list operations
        list_allowed_methods = []
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'patch']

        #Exclude some fields
        excludes = ('first_name', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'last_name', 'password',)

    #Apply filter for the requesting user
    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(pk=request.user.pk)

    #Override urls such that GET:users/ is actually the user detail endpoint
    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
        ]
```

Using something other than the primary key for getting the details of a resource is explained in more detail in the [Tastypie Cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls)

Comment: please note that `apply_authorization_limits` has been deprecated. [see](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/809)

Comment: So how can we achieve the same result in later versions?